# General Swift Logic Question with Closures

Tags: swift

Looking at the following code, why is the response "Hi, Jake" instead of "Hi, John?" To me the closure is being called after the `name = "John"`, so shouldn't that change the name inside the closure as well? Of course the answer is no, but why?

```
var name = "Jake"
let closure = { [name] in
    print ("Hi, \(name)!")
}
name = "John"
closure()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you explicitly told the closure to [**capture**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID103) `name` – which is the value before the declaration of the closure.

Remove `[name] in` and it will print `Hi, John!`